# Apache reverse proxy not passing custom headers to the target server

Tags: apache-http-server, authentication, headers, kerberos

I have configured Apache as reverse proxy to my PostGraphile service. My idea is to use Apache to do kerberos authentication and then make PostGraphile service available to authenticated users.

I also need to pass some custom headers to that service.

At this point in time I can have either kerberos authentication turned on or headers passed. As soon as I turn authentication on headers are not appearing on the service side.

This is my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location />
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Kerberos Authentication"
    KrbAuthRealsm MY.REALM
    KrbServiceName HTTP

    BrowseMatch Windows gssapi-no-negotiate
    KrbMethodNegotiate on

    KrbMethodK5Passwd off

    Krb5Keytab /path/to/keytab.keytab

    # require valid-user # with this line uncomented headers defined later do not appear on service side
    require all granted # with this line uncommented headers defined later do appear on service side however any user can access the service

    ProxyPass 'http://my.service:5000'
    ProxyPassReverse 'http://my.service:5000'
  </Location>
  <Proxy *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from local.ip.range
  </Proxy>

  RequestHeader set MYCUSTOMHEADER foo
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm out of ideas.

I have been reading Apache documentation, auth_mode_kerb documentation, stack threads and blogs but it seems I'm encountering some weird bug here or missing something fundamental...

Any hints would be very welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After experimenting I finally landed at solution that meets my needs however I must admit I have no idea why is this working the way it seems to be working.

If I add following to my configuration I can pass information I need within `Authorization` header.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%1]
RequestHeader add Authorization %{RU}e
```

However other custom headers are still not showing up, and this will remain a mystery to me.

---

edit:

After fiddling more I discovered that as soon as I overwrite Authorization header my custom headers show up as well. Would be great to understand if this is intended behavior (maybe security feature) or a bug within mod-auth-kerb..

---

edit2:

After 2 years somebody pointed out that I might have had a typo in configuration:

```
KrbAuthRealsm MY.REALM
```

I cannot check this since I don't have access to original system I was working on. And also I can't even say thank you to that person since after pointing out the typo that person removed a comment...